# Move cubes from position A to position B in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following problem: there are some towers build with cubes on a table.

```
       a 
       b d
       c e
------------------- <- table
```

Now I want to move the cubes to another situation, like this one:

```
        c e
      a b d
-------------------
```

The Prolog program should print the steps to get to this situation, for example: `move cube a onto the table`, and so on. I have the first situation represented in Prolog:

```
clean(t). % t is the table, you can always put things there
clean(X) :- \+ on(_,X). % X is the top element, if there is nothing above it

on(a,b). % a is on b
on(b,c). % b on c
on(d,e). % d on e
on(c,t). % c on the table
on(e,t). % and e on the table
```

Now my problem is to find an solution to make Prolog print the steps to the new situation. My first problem is, how to tell Prolog how the new situation looks like. I tried it with some lists, but I didn´t succeed until now.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think you may need to state other facts, maybe something like nextTo(a, b)?

Comment: what do you mean with nextTo? Left or right? Or above?

Comment: I was saying that you may not be able to make prolog print your new situation if you don't have extra facts. I meant left&right, but if that's ambiguous for you, try to use another identifier name.

Comment: hm okay, but how can I print the steps which cubes to move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encode the problem state by having facts of the `on/2` predicate in your database, then you can only change that state by using `assert` and `retract` to change the database (and your predicates probably have to be declared `dynamic` as well). This is unwieldy. A nicer solution is to pass around the problem state as a parameter to your solving predicates (and maybe hide that structure behind a wrapper predicate). This works much better with the backtracking that you're probably going to need to implement the search for the solution.